# Android - Context for BillingClient inside Fragment

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library, billingclient

I have a single activity application (java) and one of the fragments contains Subscription buttons. I'm setting up the Google Play Billing Library but when I set up the following:

```
private BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getActivity())
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build();
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please provide a valid Context.
at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient$Builder.build
```

I also tried

```
getContext()
```

and

```
getActivity.getApplicationContext()
```

but didn't work either. Neither did requireContext().

What context should I pass if I'm inside a fragment?

**UPDATE:**

The subscription fragment is called by the SignUpFragemnt:

```
public class SignUpFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false);

    Button nextButton = v.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
        Navigation.findNavController(v1).navigate(R.id.subscriptionV3Fragment);
    });

    return v;
}
}
```

And this is Subscription Fragment:

```
public class SubscriptionV3Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SubscriptionV3Fragment";

    SkuDetails monthlyDetails;
    SkuDetails annualDetails;

    Context context = getActivity();

    private PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {

        }
    };

    private BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(requireContext())
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subscription_v3, container, false);

        startConnection();

        Button monthlySubscribe = v.findViewById(R.id.monthlySubscribeBut);
        monthlySubscribe.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }


    private void startConnection() {
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // PENDING
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    querySubscriptionProducts();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void querySubscriptionProducts() {
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add("sub_monthly");
        skuList.add("sub_annual");

        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<SkuDetails> list) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: " + list);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `requireContext()`

Comment: @che10 I also tried that. I got "Fragment MyFragment{19daa01} (09338a0b-b761-42fe-bcbc-798e59c47eba)} not attached to a context."

Comment: Then it might be some issue with how the Fragment is being attached. Can you paste some code in reference to that? How the `Fragment` is being used in your project?

Comment: @che10 just added an update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not the `context` in this case, the problem is where it is being access from. When this part of your code is called, other methods of FragmentLifeCycle are still in work.

```java
private BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(requireContext())
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build();
```

I would suggest you move it down inside after `OnCreateView()` or even better inside `onViewCreated()`

Just assign it up top

```java
private BillingClient billingClient;
```

Then inside `onViewCreated()` you can do this

```java
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(requireContext())
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build();
```

Comment: Another way to put it is that google's example for in app billing is wrong :-(

Answer (score -1):

change getActivity() with getContext()